# Inserting decimal with thousands separator comma into MySQL database

Tags: mysql

In my C# program I am writing to a file after parsing an imported CSV file. I am using this file to insert rows into a database. Almost all fields are being inserted correctly. The problem I'm having is inserting decimals greater than 999.99. For instance, "1,000.00" is being inserted as "1.00" and "26,400.50" is being inserted as "26.50". The database column type is DECIMAL(12,2). Any way to remedy this?

Comment: You probably need to handle the values in application level and then convert to proper format before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Set your decimal value in your database as DECIMAL(6,2)

Comment: It's set to DECIMAL(12,2)

Comment: It seems like you need the FORMAT function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: I'm going to try adding culture info to the Convert.ToDecimal method.